# How to share an SSRS Report Template across TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, tfs, ssrs-2012

The standard method of implementing a Reporting Services report template is to create an .RDL (report file) and place it in the Visual Studio Report Project template folder at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\ReportProject`

Since this is a purely local approach, is there a way to implement a **shared and source controlled template** that can be used from the new item menu?

Our current solution for this issue is to store our templates in our report solution, and copy/paste them for new reports. Just wondering if there's a better alternative.

Comment: That's what we do too :-) (We prefix them with Z to push them to the bottom.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create this as a .vsix extension and then share it. If you update the package and version all Visual Studio instanced that have it installed will prompt the user to update.

How to: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsx/2014/06/10/creating-a-vsix-deployable-project-or-item-template-with-custom-wizard-support/

Although you can setup your own repo to load it from, It's much easyer to use http://marketplace.visualstudio.com for distribution.

Comment: I can't see adding templates with company specific fonts/images to the marketplace. How hard is it to set up a repo? Do you have a good link?

Comment: If you do an internet search you will find many options for this. Have a look, try something and if you have additional issues then create a new question.